# MatLab: concatenate 2 columns of an array

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to import a `.csv` file to work with the data inside MATLAB, but I am having some troubles.

The file contains one column with a correlative number, the second column contains a float number (with decimal numbers separated by a comma).

When I read the file with `csvread()` I obtain an array with 3 columns (one column with the correlative number, another column with the integer number of the float number and another one with the decimal part of the float number).

The next step I would like to do is to concatenate the second and third column of that array using a `,` between them so I can assemble the original float number.

Is there any way to do that? Or a better way to import that kind of data??

This is an example of the raw csv file:

```
1,1,143526
2,1,143524
3,1,143472
4,1,143413
5,1,143472
6,1,143485
7,1,143556
8,1,143552
9,1,143644
10,1,143559
```

And what I need is one array with this:

```
[1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10]
```

And another one with this:

```
[1.143526    1.143524    1.143472    1.143413    1.143472    1.143485 ...
1.143556    1.143552    1.143644    1.143559]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include one or two rows of the CSV file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that by using a comma `,` as separator for decimal numbers, MATLAB (or better: `csvread`) assumes that you have 3 rows:

```
1  ,  1  ,  143526
```

instead of two rows, where the second one would be a floating point number, as desired:

```
1    1.143526
```

The vectors can easily be combined by dividing the part behind the comma such that it becomes `0.143526`. You can find the number by which you have to divide by

```
10.^(ceil(log10(x)))
```

For `143526` this gives `10^6`, so dividing by this gives `0.143526` as desired.
Now we just have to add the integer part from the second column.

Assuming you read the CSV file to a matrix called `X`, you can create the two vectors by

```
corrNumber = X(:,1);
floatNr = X(:,2) + X(:,3) ./ 10.^(ceil(log10(X(:,3))));
```

As described in a comment, numbers like `1.0998` lead to problems with this approach. The only way to solve this without changing from `csvread` to e.g. `fscanf` is, if the number of decimals is fixed. Then we can get the maximal scaling factor by inserting a `max`:

```
floatNr = X(:,2) + X(:,3) ./ 10.^(ceil(max(log10(X(:,3)))));
```

Comment: It works perfectly in MATLAB.
But working with the original array I am having another trouble:
The values that go below 1.1000, like 1.0998 convert in corrNr = 1; floatNr = 998.
The concatenated number is then1.998 instead of 1.0998.
That's because MATLAB throw away zeros located at the left side.
Is also any solution for avoid that?

Comment: @osuarez Using a fix number of decimal places as my code shown as variable or read string and count decimal places.

Comment: @osuarez I edited my answer to include a fixed number of decimals. I hope this works for you. Otherwise, we'll have to replace `csvread` by some more low-level input routine.

Comment: Unfortunately the decimals are not fixed. It varies from 6 to 4 decimals.
So I guees I would need to use the fscanf function? 
I have been making some tests with that function but still does not have an adequate return from the .csv.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my .csv has 7 header lines. Can I also jump this headers untill the data with the <code>csvread</code>?

Comment: Well there it gets tricky.  The major problem is that the `,` is used for both separating columns and as decimal point. I will try to think of something later today.

Comment: I finally solved this question changing the separator character used in my region by the OS (Windows 7 in that case).
It is possible to change this by means of Control Panel.
With this change the decimal separator is now a dot instead of a period may now importing the .csv directly from MATLAB.

Comment: @osuarez I think that is a very good idea - probably the best possible solution for such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If decimal numbers are numbers with fixed format (equal decimal places), you can adapt a new matrix

```
d = 4 %% decimal places
n = lenght(M) %% M from cvsread
for i= 1:n
   A(i, 1) = M(i, 1)
   A(i, 2) = M(i, 2) + M(i, 3) / 10^d
end
```